# Stuck in a recursion maze

Tags: java, recursion, maze

Need a push in the right direction for a class assignment. I've read other posts that mentioned creating a variable/method to store the path traveled, but not sure how to get about it...
    Edited 9/28/16
    was able to get to the end point of the maze but still haven't figured  out 
    how to print only the path taken; I really need to

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Maze
{
    private static int rows, cols, startRow, startCol, nextRow, nextCol;
    private static int endRow = 3;
    private static int endCol = 34;
    private static char[][] mazeBoard;
    //private static char start = 'S';
    private static char end = 'E';
    //private boolean finish = false;
    private char[][] explored = new char[rows][cols];

    //construct the maze board
    public Maze() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"));
        rows = in.nextInt();
        cols = in.nextInt();
        startRow = in.nextInt();
        startCol = in.nextInt();

        //fill out the mazeBoard
        mazeBoard = new char[rows][cols];
        int i = 0;
        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            String inLine = in.nextLine();
            if (inLine.isEmpty())
            {
            continue;   
            }
            for (int j = 0;j < cols; j++)
            {   
            char nextChar = inLine.charAt(j);
            mazeBoard[i][j] = nextChar;
            System.out.print(nextChar);     
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;        
        }
        in.close();
    }
    //updated the move method from void to boolean
    public boolean move(int row, int col, int prevRow, int prevCol)
{
    boolean finish = false; 
    prevRow = row;
    prevCol = col;
    //show location
    System.out.println("row: " + row + " col: " + col);

    //base case1 to check for out of bounds and not the previous position
    if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= rows || col >= cols || row != prevRow || col != prevCol)
        {   return false;   }   
    //base case2 to see if reached exit/end point
    if (row == endRow && col == endCol)
    {
        System.out.println("Found the exit!");
        return true;
    }   
    //base case3 to check for wall
    if (mazeBoard[row][col] == '+' || mazeBoard[row][col] == '*')
        {   return false;   }
    mazeBoard[row][col] = '*';  
        //try to move down
        if (move(row + 1, col, prevRow, prevCol))
            {   return true;    }
        //try to move right
        if (move(row, col + 1, prevRow, prevCol))
            {   return true;    }
        //try to move up
        if (move(row - 1, col, prevRow, prevCol))
            {   return true;    }
        //try to move left
        if (move(row, col - 1, prevRow, prevCol))
            {   return true;    }   
            row = prevRow;
            col = prevCol;
    return false;   
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Maze maze = new Maze();
        maze.move(startRow, startCol);
    }

}
```

====
so I'm not sure how to implement a method to keep track of path traveled, any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some explanation about what you are trying to achieve would be appreciated. Without looking closer at your code, I guess you want to solve the maze? If so, do you have to use a specific algorithm or just solve it? Furthermore, could you describe your implementation and the problem(s) you encountered more detailed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Please also refer to this Stack Overflow Question Checklist to help you ask a question that will help you in the right direction. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to wait until you find the solution.  Then simply record the successful moves as you crawl back up that branch of the call tree.  Each winning call prepends its move to the front of the return value and passes that back up the stack.  This would be something like

```
result = move(rowM + 1, colM);
if result != ""
    return "D" + result;   // "D" for a move right
else {
    // Try a move right ...
```

You do have a couple of things to fix.  Most of all, you have to block taking a step you've already taken.  Right now, when your search hits a dead end, it keeps repeating the final step and backtrack in an infinite recursion.

Second, you'll need to implement logic to abort other searches once you've found one solution.  Setting a **finish** doesn't help much; that's a local variable, and you need to communicate to the calling program that you've failed or succeeded.

Is that enough to move you to the next step?